# Eclipse correct way to add dependency to another Maven project?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have three maven projects all under active development, One is a common library the other two perform ui tasks and use the common project.

In eclipse what is the alternative of adding the common library project as a dependency manually like so:

```
 build path -> require projects on the build path
```

[image: require projects on the build path]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maven is the build tool, eclipse an IDE. You should focus on the Build Tool, so add the dependency in the maven typic pom.xml.

You could only add dependencys that have been downloaded into your local repository!

In your case you have to install your dependency into your local repository. This is done by the `mvn install` command. You could call it by rightclick on the `pom.xml` file of the dependency you like to use, select `run-as`->`maven install`.

Comment: How do you add another project that is currently developed as a dependency?

Comment: First, you must install the dependency, use `mvn install`, then you get a `groupId`, a `artifactId` and a `version`. Open the pom.xml and add theese informations to a xml-node called `<dependencies>`. You can find examples in the www.

Comment: can i run mvn install from within eclipse? can you update your question with this info, i will accept it, thank you!

Comment: @user648026 Lets solve all questions first. Please look at the icon of the Project inside eclipse, it might be a yellow/blue folder symbol. Do you have a small blue `M` on the upper left side of the icon?

Comment: sometimes, when no `M` is there, its a maven project anyway. But if a m is there you can be quite sure, its a maven project.